# Como listar todos los calendarios en la api de google calendar (calendarList.list())

Tags: javascript, nodejs, google-api, google-calendar

tengo problemas a la hora de listar los calendarios compartidos, me devuelve un arreglo vacio siempre, estoy trabajando con una cuenta de servicio, gracias a buscar por todos lados y la documentacion pude insertar eventos y listarlos pero siempre con un 'calendarId' de por medio, la idea es que la gente no se autentique sino mostrar los datos de mis calendarios y a lo sumo insertar eventos

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
require("dotenv").config();

const GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.private_key;
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL = process.env.client_email;
const GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER = process.env.project_number;
const GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID = process.env.calendar_id;

const SCOPES =  [
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
];

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
   GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
   null,
   GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
   SCOPES
);

const calendar = google.calendar({
  version: "v3",
  project: GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER,
  auth: jwtClient,
});


const listCalendars = async() => {
   const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
   keyFile: "./keys.json",
   scopes: SCOPES,
});

 const authClient = await auth.getClient();
 google.options({auth: authClient});

const res = await calendar.calendarList.list()    
console.log(res.data)

};
listCalendars();
```

Esto me devuelve:

```
{
 kind: 'calendar#calendarList',
 etag: '"p32sajrmeoad800o"',
 nextSyncToken :'CLip7s7CmoADEjlhcnRlZmFjdG8tMzkyODIzQGFydGVmYWN0by0zOTI4MjMuaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20=',
 items: []
}
```

El codigo esta realizado en base a un tutorial perdido y a la documentacion de google pero no logro entender honestamente que es lo que falta, este mismo codigo me deja ver eventos de un calendario en particular e insertar eventos en dicho calendario pero, nuevamente, no me deja ver la lista de calendarios (los cuales estan todos con la configuracion indicada desde la consola y google calendar, ese no es el problema)
Espero puedan ayudarme y me disculpo de antemano si el codigo les hace doler los ojos xd, saludos!

Comment: Por lo visto estás usando una "service account". Siendo ese el caso, te faltó especificar el "subject", aunque si es una cuenta de gmail, creo que una "service account" no te funcionará y tendrás que usar el método de 3 legged Oauth.

Comment: Amigo! Muchas gracias por responder, dónde debería ir el "subject"?, voy a buscar sobre eso...y el método al que te refieres es el de autenticación con el botón de Google y demás? Yo solo quiero que se vean los eventos y en caso de cambiar algo hacerlo yo desde el código, en lo posible sin que el cliente tenga que auntentificarse, quizás no me doy cuenta y no es posible, gracias igualmente seguiré buscando info, pensé que iba a ser más fácil xd